# Time in 0 gravity points

Tags: gravity, time, time-dilation, lagrange-point

If being close to a supermassive body like a black hole makes time pass more slowly for us than for an observer from a point of view with a weaker gravitational field, if we get to be at a point in space where there is no gravitational influence, would that make X time on earth a long time at that point?
I'm not talking about a Lagrangian point, where as I've studied, the field strengths cancel each other out. (I am a high school student from Spain).
If we could spend our lives at a point with this characteristic, would we be longer lived or would we still live ~85 earth years?
Has it been calculated what would be the time equivalence in such a place?

Comment: remember that perspective of time is the same for all the observers irrespective of the time dilation. If a person experiences 1 second on earth, the person next to a SMBH will also experience the same 1 second, in simple terms. if you are familiar with the term spacetime, your time co-ordination is rotated to certain angle respect to another frame in time dilation if you live for 85 years on earth, you will live the same 85 years near a super massive black hole

Comment: Your edit, removing the part about life-span, makes the existing answers look odd. Please can you revert the edit (or I can do it for you).

Comment: BTW, gravitational time dilation isn't exactly a function of gravitational field strength. It's correlated with the difference in gravitational potential energy. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/564031/123208 FWIW, the time dilation due to Earth's gravity (compared to the time where the gravitational potential due to Earth's gravity is zero) is approximately 2.19 seconds per century. You can calculate it using the equation here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/528660/123208

Comment: @JamesK I reverted the edit. Thank you for the recommendation, I'm new here.

Comment: I saw your question on Phil SE. I should warn you that you are unlikely to get good advice there, as many cranks are running wild there and hardly any of the users of Phil SE even notice. To search for truth, analytic philosophy is indeed necessary, together with empirical science, but what is trendy in philosophy today is mostly irrelevant to truth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> makes time pass more slowly for us

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of time dilation, which only says anything about the relative rates that clocks run compared to a clock that is in your own frame of reference.

All observers "experience time" in the same way.

The second problem with your post is that "gravitational time dilation" is not directly connected to the gravitational field strength. What matters is the gravitational potential. The difference in the relative rates at which clocks run (according to observers with those clocks) depends on the difference in gravitational potential.

A region with "zero gravitational field" is just a place where the gradient of the potential is zero. It says nothing about the gravitational potential itself. For example, the gravitational field at the centre of the Earth is zero but clocks here would appear to run slow compared with clocks on the Earth's surface.

An observer on (the surface of the)  Earth will judge that a clock in orbit is running faster (ignoring any time dilation due to relative motion); a clock a long way from the Sun will run a bit faster still and one beyond our Galaxy a little bit faster again.

Edit: For example, the size of the effect can be approximated by saying a clock far from the Galaxy would run at $\sim 1 + GM/Rc^2$ times the rate of a clock orbiting the Galaxy at the distance of the Sun (there is also time dilation due to relative motion, which I'm ignoring), where $M$ is the mass interior to the Sun's Galactic orbit and $r$ is the radius of that orbit. $M \sim 10^{11}$ solar masses and $r \sim 8000$ pc gives an increased rate of $1 + 6\times 10^{-7}$ (or about 20 seconds per year).

Comment: Can we quantify this "a little bit faster"?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann about 20 seconds/year - see edit

Answer (score 3):

**Question**: If we could spend our lives at a point with this characteristic, would we be longer lived or would we still live ~85 earth years?

**Simple Answer**: No

**Abstract**

> Perspective of time is the same for all the observers irrespective of the time dilation. If a person experiences 1 second on earth, the person next to a SMBH will also experience the same 1 second, in simple terms. if you are familiar with the term spacetime, your time co-ordination is rotated to certain angle respect to another frame

Have look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/what-is-time-does-it-flow-and-if-so-what-defines-its-direction) for more clarity.

To understand about time dilation, I hope you are familiar with [Euclidian Metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), if not, it just about three dimensional graph where you will find some co-ordinates using Pythogoras theorem, along with that you will have a separate one dimensional graph which is time, if you record an event in this four co-ordinates (i.e t,x,y,z), you are recording events in spacetime !

Each person will have their own graphs of spacetime, where each one of them will have their own "cloaks" to say so, their each person's graph is rotated with respect to one another.

Lets visualize it even simpler:

Suppose there is no Time dilation our time graphs would be parallel like this:
[image]
if you record an event at Time B, I will also record the event to be happened at B' where these two readings are the same.

But in time dilation my time graph is rotated with respect to your time graph like this:
[image]

if you record an even at B, I will record the event slightly ahead of B', So we can say that your clock and my clock are running differently.

Its important to note that the distance between time A and B is same as A' and B', only thing is it is rotated, So the perspective of time is same for all the observers

This will answer your question, if you live 85 years at Earth, you will live the same 85 years near a supermassive blackhole.

**Question 2**: Has it been calculated what would be the time equivalence in such a place?

Einstein general relativity will show you how time dilates in different circumstances. You cannot calculate time dilation without a proper reference frame.
Again even if you are under the influence of "zero Gravity", you can still experience time dilation if you are moving relatively. Have a look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241772/what-is-time-dilation-really#:%7E:text=Time%20dilation%20simply%20means%20that,time%20between%20the%20two%20points.)